# Creating windows folder and then writing a file in it from Unix

Tags: unix, mount

I am trying to write a `shell script` which will call up a `SQL file` and spool output in a `csv` file.

This `csv` file needs to be placed in a `shared drive` in a folder having `date stamp`.

So I need to create a folder in `windows shared drive` and then write the `csv` file over there.

I tried mounting the `windows drive` in `Unix` but looks like my `Unix OS` doesn't have mount command. It throws error.

> *sh: mount:  not found.*

Comment: Are you sure you have permissions to mount devices? Try to run script as root user, mount comes as part of the core utils of linux so it has to be in your path, the problem may be that you have not permissions to run it with your user

Comment: I am not sure if I will get the root access.Do we have any options other than mounting

Answer (score 0):

Log in as root try again.. If you still can't mount the windows share install the nfstools or samba..